# A word to indicate a decrease in performance

Tags: word-request

There is a word which means "decrease in performance", usually used in negative context. Here are some examples:

"The city's power station usually gives a steady voltage of 220V, but at 9PM, when the TV series ends and everyone turns on a teapot, the voltage may ... even to 215V".

"This algorithm solves a random instance of a problem in several seconds, but there are some specific instances on which its running time ... up to a minute".

"During the rush-hour the capacity of major streets ... significantly".

For Russian speakers: the exact Russian analog is "проседать", but I can't find a desired translation anywhere.

**UPD:** I've got one exact word on a tip of my tongue. Here are some words which may fit the gaps but are not what I need: sink, drop, sag, plummet, decrease.

Probably "degrade" is the best match I could think of.

Comment: @Max I tried Google translate but it does not provide the word I'm looking for, none word of this three matches. I'll try to give more examples.

Comment: Can you explain why the related words don't fit? This will help us discover the nuance. Also, consider "decline" and "depreciate".

Comment: @Max They do fit, though these words have broader usage. The one I'm talking about is precisely about performance, or throughput. Maybe it is even some kind of a technical term.

Comment: `degrade` is a verb and usually related to quality of something is getting worse (more like something damaged), but the quality does not necessary mean algorithm slowdown or decreasing capacity of something. More appropriate words to use are `reduction` or `drop` (e.g. frame-per-second drop in video player) as mentioned in  the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

Drop

> Make or become lower, weaker, or less.

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drop))

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It is not the one I have on a tip of my tongue; I'll update the answer and include several words which may fit but are not words I'm searching for. Anyway, my upvote for a technically correct answer!

Answer (score 3):

You should go for a "decline/reduction" in performance. These words are more common and idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

An appropriate word might be 'poorer'

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/poor) says:

> **poorer** (*adj*.) If you describe an amount, rate, or number as poor, you mean that it is less than expected or less than is considered reasonable.

You could use this word in your example sentences like this:

> There are some specific instances on which its running time **may be poorer** by up to a minute".
>
> During rush hour, the capacity of major streets **is** significantly **poorer**.